# C++, cast a vector<specific_type> to vector<boost::variant>

Tags: c++, vector, boost, boost-variant

I have a function signature, that take a `vector<specific_type>` as argument and call another function that has `vector<boost::variant<specific_type, ...>>` as argument. A simple transfer of the argument does not work. I found repacking as only solution, but this is likely not the most performant solution. Is a simple cast somehow possible?

Minimal example:

```
#include "boost/variant.hpp"

#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef boost::variant<int, std::string> test_t;

void inner(std::vector<test_t> a) {}

void outer(std::vector<int> a) {
    // the following does not work:
    //inner(a);
    //inner((std::vector<test_t>) a);
    //inner(const_cast<std::vector<test_t>>(a));
    //inner(reinterpret_cast<std::vector<test_t>>(a));
    //inner(static_cast<std::vector<test_t>>(a));
    //inner(dynamic_cast<std::vector<test_t>>(a));

    // only "valid" solution
    std::vector<test_t> b;
    for (const int i : a) {
        b.push_back(i);
    }
    inner(b);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 4, 2 };
    outer(a);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is a simple cast somehow possible?

Nope. There is no such cast.

> this is likely not the most performant solution

Correct, we can do a bit better by using the [`vector` range constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> ```
> template< class InputIt >
> vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
>         const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

which we would use like:

```
void outer(std::vector<int> const& a) {
    inner({a.begin(), a.end()});
}
```

Comment: This avoids the extra allocation of memory but iterates the complete vector, too? The syntax is quite nice, of course.

Comment: @gerion No way around that. You have to construct a `variant` for each element - can't do that without actually looking at all the elements.

Comment: @gerion, can you at least move the objects to the variant vector?